# How to disable or enable cookie when using FormsAuthentication in ASP.NET webforms?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, forms-authentication

I need to use FormsAuthentication to authenticate login for users using ajax, I know I can't use FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("UserName",false) because there's no redirection when using ajax.
What can I use to set that this user authorized.
Tried to use:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("UserName", false);
```

But there's cookie here and I don't want to use cookie.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the encryption/decryption/expiration aspects of Forms Authentication separately from the request/response cycle (e.g. cookies).

For example: you can get the auth token as a string like this:

```
// create a ticket for "myusername" which expires in 15 minutes
string authToken = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(new FormsAuthenticationTicket("myusername", false, 15));
```

And then when use receive it back from the user from some custom approach (you didn't really specify what you're going to use instead of cookies) you use [FormsAuthentication.Decrypt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.decrypt.aspx) to check if it's valid. Note that you have to trap exception **and** check for null in order to check validity.

```
// decrypt receivedAuthToken string which was received somehow in your request
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(receivedAuthToken);
```

But then you have to also manage the renewal process yourself too:

```
var newTicket = FormsAuthentication.RenewTicketIfOld(authTicket);
var newToken = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket)
```